# Nexus marks every https proxy Maven repository as Unavailable and Untrusted Remote

Tags: maven, nexus

I have the latest version of Nexus installed and every time I add a new proxy repository that is `https` e.g. https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/ it marks it as `Remote Automatically Blocked and Unavailable` and `Untrusted Remote`. The problem is that it doesn't always work to re-specify the remote repository as `http` instead of `https`.

How can I fix/troubleshoot this?

Comment: what do the logs tell you? is there a trust / certificate exception when nexus tries to connect to the remote https repositories? Is there a proxy in the network for the https connections too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure the trust store in the JVM running Nexus. In Nexus Pro this can be done via the user interface. In open source you have to do it manually on the command line. Its all documented in [the book chapter about SSL](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/ssl-sect-client-cert.html).